# How to remove specific attribute from JSONB array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres JSONB column that holds an array like below: I want to run a query which removes the "hide" attribute from any of these objects.

```
[
    {
        "data": "id",
        "width": 25
    },
    {
        "data": "field_1",
        "width": 125
    },
    {
        "data": "field_3",
        "hide": true,
        "width": 170
    },
    {
        "data": "addedby",
        "width": 178
    },
    {
        "data": "field_67",
        "width": 125,
        "hide": true
    }
]
```

The desired output after running it would be:

```
[
    {
        "data": "id",
        "width": 25
    },
    {
        "data": "field_1",
        "width": 125
    },
    {
        "data": "field_3",
        "width": 170
    },
    {
        "data": "addedby",
        "width": 178
    },
    {
        "data": "field_67",
        "width": 125
    }
]
```

I know to delete a single attribute from a JSONB attribute looks like:

```
update mytable set columnsettings = columnsettings -hide where tableid=55
```

But how do I specify to remove this attribute from the entire array?
FYI, I'm running postgres 11

Answer (score 1):

Just use `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function along with subtraction operator in order to derive every element within the array while subtracting `hide` attribute, and then aggregate seperated elements within an array again such as

```
SELECT JSONB_PRETTY( JSONB_AGG(jsdata) ) AS result
  FROM ( SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS( columnsettings ) - 'hide' AS jsdata
           FROM mytable ) AS t
```

**OR** within an *Update Statement*

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET columnsettings = ( SELECT JSONB_AGG(jsdata)
                           FROM ( SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS( columnsettings ) 
                                      - 'hide' AS jsdata
                                    FROM mytable ) AS t )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3eb68b5a61f187cc96e786a0452a4217)</kbd>